# SQL select, execute and show all rows

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I try to calculate and order the distance(nearest) between an user and malls' location. I need to do it for every mall rows but I don't want to use "while" because of the performance issues. What should I do?

The code below only shows last row after execution.

```
@UserId INT
AS 
DECLARE
@UserLat DECIMAL(9,6),
@UserLon DECIMAL(9,6),
@MallLat DECIMAL(9,6),
@MallLon DECIMAL(9,6),
@geo1 geography,
@geo2 geography

SELECT TOP 1 @UserLat = l.Lat, @UserLon = l.Lon  FROM Location l WHERE l.UserId = @UserId ORDER BY l.LocationId DESC

SELECT @MallLat = m.MallLatitude, @MallLon = m.MallLongitude FROM Mall m

SET @geo1 = geography::Point(@UserLat, @UserLon, 4326)
SET @geo2 = geography::Point(@MallLat, @MallLon, 4326)

SELECT ROUND(@geo1.STDistance(@geo2)/1000,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the calculation into the `SELECT` of `MALL`. This will give you the sorted distance from `@geo1` to each `MALL` row:

```
...
SELECT TOP 1 @UserLat = l.Lat, @UserLon = l.Lon  
FROM Location l WHERE l.UserId = @UserId 
ORDER BY l.LocationId DESC

SET @geo1 = geography::Point(@UserLat, @UserLon, 4326)

SELECT ROUND(@geo1.STDistance(
    geography::Point(MallLatitude, MallLongitude, 4326))/1000,2) AS distance 
FROM Mall
ORDER BY distance
```

I should note that I tested this on SQL Server 2012, and not the version you have - 2008.